# UNION syntax for SUM-ing multiple COUNTs

Tags: mysql, count, sum, union

These queries work individually.  How do I write the UNION to SUM all results?

```
SELECT SUM(players) FROM `tournament_players` FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p1_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p2_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p3_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p4_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track but with an additional `FROM` keyword. Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(players) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p1_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p2_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p3_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` FROM `tournament_players` WHERE `foursome_1_p4_name` IS NOT NULL AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND flight = '8 AM'
) `tournament players`
```

Comment: Thank you!  So simple.  Example I was working from lacked correct syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want this, place your individual queries inside of a sub-query to get the `sum()`:

```
SELECT SUM(players) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` 
    FROM `tournament_players` 
    WHERE `foursome_1_p1_name` IS NOT NULL 
        AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
        AND flight = '8 AM'
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` 
    FROM `tournament_players` 
    WHERE `foursome_1_p2_name` IS NOT NULL 
        AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
        AND flight = '8 AM'
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` 
    FROM `tournament_players` 
    WHERE `foursome_1_p3_name` IS NOT NULL 
        AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
        AND flight = '8 AM'
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) as `players` 
    FROM `tournament_players` 
    WHERE `foursome_1_p4_name` IS NOT NULL 
        AND `tournament` BETWEEN 13 AND 17 
        AND flight = '8 AM'
) x -- place your alias here
```